# What is the equation of the bottom half of the parabola $x + (y - 2)^2 = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, conic-sections

A parabola has the equation:

$$x + (y - 2)^2 = 0$$

I can't find the $y$ without getting the equation into some weird recursion.

Comment: Have you tried the quadratic formula?

Comment: Try to look at it as $x(y) = -(y-2)^2$.

Comment: Recursion ?  What recursion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to solve for $y$ and take the negative branch.

We write $x + (y - 2)^2 = 0 \Rightarrow y=2\pm(-x)^{1/2}$.

Thus, the bottom half of the parabola is $y=2-\sqrt{-x}$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: Maybe add something like $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$...